# Can setTimeout be used with a function inside a closure?

Tags: javascript

Can JavaScript's `setTimeout` function be used with functions that are inside a closure? What if the call to `setTimeout` is made from within that same closure?

With my attempts, it appears that you cannot.  I'm not sure if I'm missing anything, though.

Basically, I would like to do this:

```
var ButtonCycler = (function() {
  var ButtonCycler = {};
  var autoCycle;
  var idx = 0;
  var buttonIds = [];
  buttonIds[0] = "id1";
  buttonIds[1] = "id2";
  //"Public" methods
  ButtonCycler.startAutoCycle = function() {
    autoCycle = true;
    cycleButtons();
  }
  ButtonCycler.stopAutoCycle = function() {
    autoCycle = false;
  }
  //Worker function (effectively private because it's in the closure)
  function cycleButtons() {
    var radioButton;
    if(autoCycle) {
      radioButton = document.getElementById(buttonIds[idx]);
      radioButton.checked = true;
      idx++;
      if(idx >= buttonIds.length) {
        idx = 0;  //Start over at first button
      }
      setTimeout('cycleButtons()',2500); //Delay for 2.5 seconds
    }
  }
  return ButtonCycler;
})(); //IIFE
```

Then in `onload` for the page, I can do this:

```
ButtonCycler.startAutoCycle();
```

And when the user manually clicks one of the radio buttons, I can do this:

```
ButtonCycler.stopAutoCycle();
```

And the mechanism for performing the cycling can be nicely encapsulated in the closure.

When I try this, I get an error that `cycleButtons` does not exist.  The initial call to `cycleButtons` succeeds, though.  It is the call initiated by the call to `setTimeout` that is failing.

Comment: Should be `setTimeout(cycleButtons, 2500);` - don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, pass function references.

Comment: No, you cannot use closures if you pass strings to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing `cycleButtons()` as a string which will later be called using `eval`. This will assume that `cycleButtons` is available at the global scope (which it is not). Instead, pass the reference to the actual function:

```
setTimeout(cycleButtons, 2500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setTimeout is incorrect and you should probably use clearTimeout to simplify your code. Here's a example of how you can simplify it:

```
var ButtonCycler = (function () {
    var ButtonCycler = {};
    var autoCycle;
    var idx = 0;
    var buttonIds = [];
    var timer;
    buttonIds[0] = "id1";
    buttonIds[1] = "id2";
    //"Public" methods
    ButtonCycler.startAutoCycle = function () {
        cycleButtons();
    }
    ButtonCycler.stopAutoCycle = function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    //Worker function (effectively private because it's in the closure)
    function cycleButtons() {
        var radioButton;
        radioButton = document.getElementById(buttonIds[idx]);
        radioButton.checked = true;
        idx = (idx < buttonIds.length - 1) ? idx + 1 : 0;

        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            cycleButtons();
        }, 2500); //Delay for 2.5 seconds      
    }
    return ButtonCycler;
})(); //IIFE
```